# Python3 not working in Ubuntu after accidetaly deleting usr/lib/ files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I recently accidentaly deleted some files and folders
( /urs/lib/pyhon3.x ), after this Python3 is not working.

`python3` gives the following error message.

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f7e77307700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried re-installing python3 by
`sudo apt-get install python3`

Still, the problem persists, I have tried unset PYTHONHOME and unset PYTHONPATH.
But nothing is working, how can we make this work?

Update(1) `pip` is not working as python is not working.
`pip install encodings` returns the following error,

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f76e2667700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped
```

Update (2) :
I have tried

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python3` then rebooot then, `sudo apt install python3`,

it gives the following error,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8 710 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
[master ccedc09] saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
 Author: rajgourav <rajgourav@euclide.ipcms1.ipcms.unistra.fr>
 8 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
Setting up python3.5 (3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.12) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007efddc85f700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package python3.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
 python3 depends on python3.5 (>= 3.5.1-2~); however:
  Package python3.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.5
 python3
```

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall python3` perhaps instead?

Comment: Hi, it is also not working. Returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I removed python3 from my ubuntu(18.0.4.5) to see if i can reproduce
the same problem.

It seems that removing python and configuration files by

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python3`

`sudo reboot`

then

`sudo apt install python3`

works

Comment: Hi, I have tried this too. It is not working, I have added the error message to the last part of the question, as I can't post long error in comments. Please have a look.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to install the module encodings with `pip install encodings` ?

Else, try to reconfigure Python3 with dpkg using the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3`

Comment: Hi, `pip` is not working either. ` pip install encodings` gives the following error.         
 ```                                                                                                                                   
 Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```